# WP-API : max num pages

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

```
$opts  = array(); // any arguments
$query = WP_Query($opts);
```

Normally, we can get **max_num_pages** by using `$totalPages = $query->max_num_pages;`
But, i make json request by using this plugin http://wp-api.org/.

When i was trying to retrieve posts using the API, the response is just json object/array of posts. The problem is, `$query->max_num_pages;` isn't accessible. I need that var to make a paginated request.

eg, i want to make a request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'wp-json/posts?page=' + currentPage + '&filter[posts_per_page]=' + perPage + '&filter[cat]=' + category
});
```

How can we fill the `currentPage` var if we don't know the *max_num_pages* ? if i just fill the `currentPage` with `1`, it's ok (because assuming it was page 1). But how i know if there is page 2, page 3?

Do you have any idea? Thanks so much, for any help :)

Answer (score 4):

WP_Query gives you what you want in the response headers.

The terms you are looking for are `X-WP-Total` and `X-WP-TotalPages`.

In jQuery you get the AJAX response headers like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: myURL,
  success: function(data, textStatus, request){
    console.log("This is the header you're looking for",request.getResponseHeader('X-WP-Total'));
  }
});
```

> **Note** *I didn't have the opportunity to test this properly as I'm not by my dev machine*

Answer (score 0):

You can get total pages from "X-WP-TotalPages" HTTP header of http response.
For example, using curl for testing from command line:

```
curl -i http://example.com/wp-json/posts
```

After you get total pages,50 pages,for example,you can loop from 1 to 50,response from above CLI also contain a useful header called "Link:",you can get more detail from this link: http://wp-api.org/guides/getting-started.html.

You need to get this value in codes by yourself.

Comment: OP is using the REST api and JavaScript. CURL is not an option.

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian  hi,maybe I want express is that you can get total-pages from response header,I use curl just for example,you need to get this value in code by yourself.I will edit this answer.